# linux bash script to create folder and move files

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Hello I need to create folder based on a filename and in this folder create another one and then move file to this second folder

example:

```
cat.jpg
create folder cat
create folder picture
move cat.jpg to picture
```

all my .jpg files are in

> /root/Desktop/My_pictures

so it should look like this:

example picture "cat.jpg"

```
/root/Desktop/My_pictures/cat/pictures/cat.jpg
```

Sorry if I'm not precise but English is not my native language.

Best Regards and Thank You

Comment: Just some pointers: `mkdir` is used to create folders. `cp` is used to copy files. `mv` is used to move and/or rename files. Type `man` followed by the command you want to see the manual page of that command. Oh, and it's best to prepare your homework on your own :-)

Comment: Please please please, don't log in to your computer as root. It is needlesly dangerous and especially when being a novice writing scripts, you might make a mistake and delete all your files.

Answer (score 6):

You can also remove the `ls *.jpg` and simply use [shell globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

for full_filename in *jpg; do
  extension="${full_filename##*.}"
  filename="${full_filename%.*}"
  mkdir -p "$filename/picture"
  mv "$full_filename" "$filename/picture"
done
```

Please **create and run** this script inside `/root/Desktop/My_pictures`.

Comment: Could you add an explanation of the string manipulation tools you are using?

Comment: @terdon Interesting. I did not know that "in *jpg" would handle filenames separated by space. Thanks!

The construction "while read i; ... ; < <(cat file.txt)" is useful for taking line by line. If you do "for i in $(cat file.txt)" you would get word by word.

Comment: Which is why you _never_ do `for i in $(cat file.txt)`, indeed. However, you don't do `while read i; ...; < <(cat file)` either, that is a classic [useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) and needlessly complex. Instead, do `while read i; do command $i; done < file`.

Answer (score 3):

A similar approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## iterate through each file whose name ends in 'jpg'
## saving it as $file. ~ is your $HOME directory
for file in ~/Desktop/My_pictures/*jpg
do
    ## basename will remove the path (~/Desktop/My_pictures) and also
    ## remove the extension you give as a second argument    
    name="$(basename "$file" .jpg)"

    ## create the directory, the -p means it will create 
    ## the parent directories if needed and it won't complain
    ## if the directory exists.
    mkdir -p ~/Desktop/My_pictures/"$name"

    ## copy the file to the new directory
    mv "$file" "~/Desktop/My_pictures/$name"
done
```

Save the script above as, for example, `~/movefiles.sh`, make it executable with `chmod +x movefiles.sh` and run it:

```
~/movefiles.sh
```